# How to prove that there exists a $K$-algebra hom $\phi : E\to L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

This question was left as an exercise in my lecture of Algebraic Geometry and I am struck on it.

Author proved that if  HNS 3  is given, i.e., the following statement is assumed true: "$E\mid K$ is a field extension, $E$ is $K$-algebra of finite type, then $E\mid K$ is algebraic extension" then HNS 1, i.e., the following statement holds: " If $L$ is algebraically closed. If $A\neq R $ (where $R$ is a ring), then $V_L(A)=\phi$.

Proof of above assertion:  We need to prove that : If $L$ is algebraically closed , $A\subseteq R=K[x_1,...,x_n]$, $A\neq R$. Then I have to prove that $V_L(R)=\phi$, i.e., we want to find $a=(a_1,...,a_n) \in L^n$ such that $f(a)= 0$ for every $f\in A$. By Krull's theorem, there exists $M \in \operatorname{Spm} R$ with $A \subseteq M$. Put $E= R/M=K[x_1,...,x_n]/M$. So, $E$ is a field extension of $K$ and $E$ is a $K$-algebra of finite type, since $E= K[x_1,...,x_n]/M$. So, by HMS 3 $E\mid K$ is an algebraic extension. Now since $L$ is algebraically closed field extension of $K$.  (**But, I am not able to prove the following statement:**) there exists a $K$-algebra homomorphism $\phi: E\to L$ which extends $ K \hookrightarrow L$.

Can you please help me with proof of this?

Thanks!

Comment: If $L'$ is the algebraic closure of $E$, then $L'$ is also the algebraic closure of $K$, because $E/K$ is algebraic. Hence $L' \cong L$, by the uniqueness of algebraic closures.

Comment: @red_trumpet I understand your comment , but how does it proves what I asked?

Comment: Restricting the isomorphism to $E$ gives you $\phi: E \to L$

Comment: @red_trumpet Thanks!